# Fluid row in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to make content of a row fluid? I have 9 boxes on my webpage, all of them are col-lg-4, so right now I have 3 rows. But what if I wanted to hide box number two in the second row... there would be a gap.

```
1 2 3 
4   6
7 8 9
```

What I would want was it to fill the gap:

```
1 2 3
4 6 7
8 9
```

Can I achive this other then going thru the elements and writing some js logic for it?

I've got the following two rows, if I hide 5, it would leave a gap:

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <h2>1</h2>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <h2>2</h2>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
 </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <h2>3</h2>
    <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa.</p>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="row">

  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <h2>4</h2>
    <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <h2>5</h2>
    <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <h2>6</h2>
    <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: please attach html, i think i know how to reach it

Comment: can you not just add the `row-fluid` class to your html element?

Comment: @Scott thanks, just what I wanted. Add it and I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the css class `.row` to `.row-fluid`

Check the documentation for more info http://bootstrap.lesscss.ru/scaffolding.html

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h2>1</h2>
        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h2>2</h2>
        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h2>3</h2>
        <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h2>4</h2>
        <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h2>5</h2>
        <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h2>6</h2>
        <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa.</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place all **.col-lg-4** in one **.row**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h2>1</h2>
        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h2>2</h2>
        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h2>3</h2>
        <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h2>4</h2>
        <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h2>5</h2>
        <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h2>6</h2>
        <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa.</p>
    </div>

</div>
```